# Sub domain and same origin policy

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Let's say that I own 2 domains www.xyz.com and ajax.xyz.com. I'd like to load my HTML and javascript from the site with prefix www and then execute an ajax request to the site prefixed with ajax. Will the same origin policy block my ajax request from www.xyz.com to ajax.xyz.com or will it work without using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet it's a bit long to set up a domain without having any admin right. I'm wondering that but I'm still on the design phase.

Comment: You can test things out locally, by editing your hosts file or by using a virtual machine ( see [vagrant](https://vagrantup.com) ).

Comment: I can't edit my host file because i don't have the rights and for using a virtual machine this is the same problem I can't install anything. The reason why I'm asking this question is because I can't test by myself quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are considered different domains, you'll have to set the CORS headers

Comment: Thank you, I had doubts about it. I wanted a confirmation about that point.